# sendTransaction v sendAndConfirmTransaction

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

So in my code I am doing the following in my backend and wondering which I should use?

```
const sig = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createMetadataTx, [mint_authority], {
      skipPreflight: false
    })
```

```
const sig = await connection.sendTransaction(
      createMetadataTx,
      [mint_authority],
      {
        skipPreflight: false,
      }
    );
```

I am guessing that the sendAndConfirmTransaction takes a little longer but confirms that the trx has been accepted for processsing, but not necessarily finalized?

And what bearing does my connection 'commitment' have on this?:

```
const connection = new Connection(tokenType.cluster, "processed");
```

Answer (score 2):

`sendTransaction` just broadcasts the transaction and does not wait for it to confirm on the network. You can then use `confirmTransaction` separately to check it the transaction was confirmed on the network.

`sendAndConfirmTransaction` does both and doesn't return until the transaction is either confirmed on the network or dropped.

You would:

- Use `sendTransaction` if you are ok with send and forget or manual confirm later
- Use `sendAndConfirmTransaction` if you want to know the transaction status before any further processing